# Need to set correct type for mongoose document

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, next.js, typegoose

I have an abstract class that takes a mongoose model and does some manipulation.

```js
export default class ItemManager {
  private _req: Request;
  private _res: Response;
  private _dbModel: mongoose.Model<any> | any; // **can't set correct type here**

  constructor(req: Request, res: Response, dbModel: any) {
    this._req = req;
    this._res = res;
    this._dbModel = dbModel;
  }

  public getItem(condition: object) {
    const promise: mongoose.DocumentQuery<any, any, {}> = this._dbModel.findOne(condition)
    return promise.then(async(item: any) => {return ...}).catch((err) => ...)
  }
}
```

**UserModel**

```js
class UserSchema extends Typegoose {
  @prop()
  firstName: string;
  ...
  @staticMethod
  public static myMethod ....
}

export const UserModel = new UserSchema().getModelForClass(UserSchema, {
  schemaOptions: {
    collection: 'users'
  }
});
```

**Usage:**

```js
import { UserModel } from '';
import ItemManager from '';
const UserManager = (req: Request, res: Response) => new ItemManager(req, res, UserModel);

router.post('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => UserManager(req, res).getItem({ my_condition }));
```

Please tell me how to correctly specify the type for `_dbModel` so that requests are processed correctly, and it is possible to work with the obtained abstract results (like: `.then(item) => item.prop = 1`) inside the `ItemManager` methods, and also use your own static methods there (`this._dbModel.myMethod()`)

Comment: For `ItemManager._dbModel`, are you fine with adding a generic? when yes this would be easy to define the correct type. Also, maybe consider upgrading typegoose to a higher major version (it seems like you are still using `typegoose`, which is superseded by `@typegoose/typegoose`, see https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/migration/migrate-6 )